# MySQL INSERT INTO skips nullability of column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Let's say we have table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col VARCHAR(100), col2 INT);
```

**Both columns are nullable.**

`ALTER TABLE tab ALTER COLUMN col2 DROP DEFAULT;` was applied on column `col2`.

Quick check:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, is_nullable
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tab';

+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME  | COLUMN_NAME  | IS_NULLABLE |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| tab         | col          | YES         |
| tab         | col2         | YES         |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Both columns are still marked as nullable**

Now if I perform

```
INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES('bar');
```

I will get an error:

> Field 'col2' doesn't have a default value.

**[db<>fiddle demo - MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d47db8f804d688229beddc02ae4f8ad)**

The same code works on PostgreSQL **[db<>fiddle demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d47db8f804d688229beddc02ae4f8ad)**

Is this some kind of bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Doc says: *If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.* I guess you took that explicit default from the column.

Comment: @juergend But if so, then wouldn't that mean that there were some _other_ default value in place, in which case we should not have seen this error message?

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81010

Comment: In my case, I removed STRICT_TRANS_TABLES and restarted MySQL service and the issue went away.

Comment: @RoxanaSh Good point: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78451be1a1a7269731dde7e31c258566)

Comment: @juergend . . . It might just be a documentation bug.